# removing text labels from basic map image, enhancing roads using python computer vision

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have and RGB-A image (png) 760x760 from azure maps shown below .
I would like to remove the text if possible and just have the roads/lines showing and then calculate the % relative area taken up by the (roads).

[image]

Have looked into thresholding the color maps and perhaps deleting invert of each but can't quite get it right just wondering if there is a easy way

```
img = map_image
img_gray = 255 - img[:, :, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax1.imshow(img_gray, cmap='gray', vmin=5, vmax=14)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.imshow(img_gray, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=50)
```

[image]

looking to end up with something like this as output grey/bw image just showing roads/lines

[image]

Comment: Try `img_gray == 128` (but instead of 128, pick the color of the background, whatever value that light gray has).

Comment: request a map tile without labels on it -- erode/dilate/median

Comment: thanks Christoph, that option seem doesn't exist for that map api unfortunately